# Adding a Stored Proc to complex type not showing up in .edmx (thus not mapped)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

1 (mvc3) I have added a stored proc to my model as mapped to a ComplextType.

Two Issues:

1) ComplextType.cs exists in class under Model1.tt BUT doesn't show up in .edmx?
2) When I try to create a controller with strongly typed views with that ComplexType.cs it errors stating that  it can't be created because ComplextType.cs is not part of the DbContextEntities class?

How can I get this complex type added to the .edmx and mapped to my dbcontext (I have done this with tables but not sure what I'm missing for the stored procedures?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't show in EDMX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who just came here from **googling**,, :)I will give the what is basically has to be done to map a stored procedure into a **ADO.Net entity**.

When mapping the **Database** to the **EDMX file(Entity Model)**.. the Entity Model automatically map the tables and complex types and ect.. But the stored procedures that are created in the database is not mapped with return complex types. We have to map it in the Function imports by creating our own complex type. This complex type can be accessed in the code.

This is done as below:

1. Right click on the **function Import** and **add new Function import**.
2. Give your name to the function and specify the **stored procedure** and
       then select **complex type**(If stored procedure returns complex type)
       or you can select scalar. IF you are selecting the **complex type** and
       you can view the columns that are returning and you can create a complex there by **create new complex type**.
3. So the return data from the **stored procedure** will be a set of those **complex type**.

One thing that should be one should access the design or the model view to update the **Entity Model**. You can not update the **Entity Model** by just right clicking on the **Entity Model**. The option of updating the model is provided only on the Model Browser and the Database design diagram. This model browser can be taken from the **Other windows of Views** in VS2010/VS2012. These information will seems boring. But trust me if you are new to this these seems big at the beginning.

Most probably you are going to create this **Entity Model** from mapping an **existing database**.

Keep in mind that even you map the Entity model form the database you can customize the Entity model by deleting the unnecessary entities(tables) and creating complex types